# Make desktop background true black

Tags: cinnamon, desktop-background

I want to make my desktop background true black--as in, the monitor emits no light. I can set the background to a black image or to the solid color black, but the monitor still emits a little bit of light. Is there any way to make it true black?

I am using the Cinnamon desktop environment.

Comment: What is the make/model of your display? This is not possible unless your display is OLED or similar. Typical panels have a backlight that spans the entire display.

Comment: My monitor is an AOC CQ27G2, I don't think it's OLED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something you can do with software.  If you have a black screen and you still see backlight, this is just how your monitor displays the color black.

Most displays have pixels that each consist of a red, a green, and a blue subpixel.  "Black" on your display is really just what you see when pixels do not contain any value for red, green, and blue sub pixels `rgb(0,0,0)`

Most computer displays (including yours) still use LCD or LED panel technology where the screen backlight illuminates the whole screen at once.  So even if the entire screen has no RGB subpixels lit, the backlight behind the pixels will still light up the whole panel.

You would need an OLED display to get what you want. OLED displays do not have a backlight for the whole screen. In OLED displays, each individual pixel provides its own light and each individual pixel can actually stop emitting light when it renders `rgb(0,0,0)`.

There's not anything you can do about this except to dim the brightness of the panel itself. Changing the brightness in Ubuntu won't reduce the backlight and would actually make the backlight even more apparent because pixels will appear darker but the backlight intensity will remain the same.